# Can I use construction screws to pull together bowed joists?

Tags: deck, fastener, pressure-treated

I am building a small (14'x12') detached deck to be placed directly on the ground with some gravel under it. I am using 4x6 pressure treated boards (UC4B) for outside frame.

I intend to use 6" TimberLOK screws from FastenMaster to stitch the frame together. All resources suggest that it's as good as lag screws.

As I put boards together, I noticed the bent on one 14' board. That makes about 1" gap between outer frame and inner joist in the middle (also 4x6).

I wonder if it's ok to use couple 6" TimberLOKs to just pull the outer board to the middle joist.

This picture is to give an idea of the project.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Lumber is rarely perfectly straight. A bigger concern is the bulk of the weight of your deck and its occupants being supported by one (not very tall) joist.

Comment: I would think that that amount of bow in a 14' run could be pulled together with a couple of TimberLOKs, and 2 1/2" into the center board is probably enough.  When you draw the pieces together, alternate between the screws, tightening one a little, then the other.  In terms of flooring, I assume that this is just a leveling frame and that you will use appropriate joists on top.

Comment: @fixer1234, that won't work unless the rim joist is pre-drilled to completely let the screws slip. Otherwise the threads from one screw lock the gap in place.

Comment: And what's a "leveling frame"?

Comment: @isherwood, the TimberLOKs are threaded only near the end.  The rest is a shaft of a smaller diameter.  Once you drive the threaded portion through, the shaft works as if you had pre-drilled the hole.  I was using "leveling frame" to refer to a level framework to act as a foundation.  I wanted to make sure the OP realized that you can't just lay plywood on what's shown, or span that distance with deckboards, and expect it to work as a floor.

Comment: Thanks, @fixer1234. The intent is to fill under front and left part, so most of frame will will rest on surface except for  right corner which is on the peer.
I then plan to put 16" OC joists from PT wood parallel to middle one and put decking above it.

Comment: If you're going to fill under those boards for support, I would use gravel.  Even wood treated for ground contact will eventually rot if you pack dirt under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be too difficult to pull that bow out, and the screws should hold it in place. I'd use a rope with a cinch loop or a ratchet strap to pull it all together, then run your screws in.

Seeing as you're pulling from end-grain you may have a hard time doing it with just screws. They might strip.

Comment: Pulling it together first with a rope or strap is a good idea.

Comment: This is a really good advice! I didn't think about pulling it with strap first. Thanks.

Comment: I would use bolts 3/8" or 1/2" bolts and washers or carriage bolts and 1 washer to pull the boards together to remove the bow. They will never come loose